# how to display html form values in the same page after submit using JavaScript? plus how to calculate form data?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a form to ask passengers in an airport their first name, sur name, their weight and their cargo weight. Then by pressing the submit button display the information in a line with the total of passengers weight and cargo weight. the the cycle goes on till we enter the last passenger information .At the end, I want to display the sum of total weights in order to keep track of the weight plane would carry.
this was the scenario,
I created form, but I cannot figure out how to solve it with primary knowledge in JavaScript.
I gave the submit button a onclick function, then define the function as below:

```
    <form  id="Passenger-form" onsubmit="return false"> <!--onsubmit, should I use or not, does it make differnce to displaying form data in the same page??-->
         <label for="First-name">First name: </label>
         <input type="text" name="First-name" placeholder="Please insert first name."><br>
        <label for="Second-name">Second name:   </label>
        <input type="text"  name="Second-name"   placeholder="Please insert second name"> <br>
        <label for="Passenger-weight">Passengers weight:   </label>
        <input type="number" name ="Passenger-weight"  placeholder="Please enter passengers weight"><br>
        <label for="cargo-weight">cargo weight:   </label>
        <input type="number"  name ="cargo-weight" placeholder="Please enter cargo weight"><br>
       <input type="submit" name ="submit" onclick="showInput(); multiply(); "> <!-- should I use &&  or semicolon in here to give two function to one onclick -->
      </form>
      <p > <span id="display"></span></p>
      
      
<body>
 <script language="JavaScript">
   
   function showInput() {
   document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 
   document.getElementById("First-name").value +" "+ document.getElementById("Second-name").value;
    }

    function multiply(){
    num1 = document.getElementById("Passenger-weight").value;
     num2 = document.getElementById("cargo-weight").value;
     document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = num1 + num2;
    }
  </script>
```

I know I am way behind the termination of my problem, but I need some clues to make it happen.
I really appreciate if anyone would help me.
in addition, JavaScript "+" sign cause a big trouble to me, since I cannot use it as an operator.

Answer (score 2):

So, there are a few ways of doing this. One is to define the `onClick` inline in the HTML:

```
<script>
  function a() { return b; }
</script>
<body>
     <button onClick="a()">Call A</button>
</body>
```

The other way is to use an event listener:

```
<button id="btn">Call function</button>

<script>
     const btn = document.getElementById("btn")
     btn.addEventListener("click", event => { 
          // Do something
          return something;
     })
</script>
```

Comment: I know about onclick function, wouldn you plz explain more, i also need to add a total number at the end, to combines all the weights,